# hibernate OneToOne with EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate

The "TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type" error thrown when tried to merge detached entity. It works if the object wasn't detached. It also works if ids aren't @EmbeddedId.

A sample repo can be found here https://github.com/joes-code/hibernate-map

```
// Asset.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "asset")
public class Asset {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AssetId id;

    @Column(name = "asset_cost"
    private BigDecimal price;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "asset_id", referencedColumnName = "asset_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    private AssetDetail assetDetail;
}

// AssetId.java
@Embeddable
public class AssetId {
    @Column(name = "asset_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer assetId;
}

// AssetDetail.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "asset_detail")
public class AssetDetail {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AssetDetailId id;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 35)
    private String description;
}

// AssetDetailId.java
@Embeddable
public class AssetDetailId {
    @Column(name = "asset_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer assetId;
}
```

I'm using Hibernate 5.4.3.Final

Any ideas what I did wrong? It seems that Hibernate is assuming Asset and AssetDetail share the same Id class?

Comment: thanks for the reply @K.Nicholas. I can make it works (there are a few ways).. but for this post I'm trying to understand why this particular mapping doesn't work.

Comment: FYI I tried _@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "asset_id", referencedColumnName = "asset_id") private AssetDetail assetDetail;_ same error. My guess is that for **unidirection OneToOne mapping with EmbeddedId**, hibernate is expecting both entity classes to share the same id class? Hoping someone from Hibernate team would see this and reply..